# Matrix URL vs query string URL

Tags: url, url-parameters, query-string

Matrix URL is a way to pass data in URL to the program, it's like a query string, but a bit nicer.

> Matrix URL notation is an idea first introduced in a 1996 proposal by
>   the founder of the web, Tim Berners-Lee.
>   Although matrix notation never made it into the HTML standard, it is
>   legal and it became popular among browser routing systems as a way to
>   isolate parameters belonging to parent and child routes. The Router is
>   such a system and provides support for the matrix notation across
>   browsers.
>
> The syntax may seem strange to you but users are unlikely to notice or
>   care as long as the URL can be emailed and pasted into a browser
>   address bar as this one can. [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero)

**It looks like this:**
`example.com/page/1/title;video=2`

I'm using Angular, and as it's a standard in Angular to use Matrix URL instead of Query strings, I also like it because it seems a bit nicer than query string and I'm not using it to pass lots of data to the program, it's just a way to show which tab is active.

But from the SEO view, since Angular is a Google project I don't think if they did not think about the SEO, but it's always better to ask: **Is using Matrix URL harmful for SEO?**

Comment: *Is using Matrix URL harmful for SEO?* Why would it be?

Comment: @closetnoc It might be harmful if search engines does not defined anything to support it, I mean, it might make no sense for Google or other search engines about how to react to such a link style

Comment: Why should *style* have anything to do with anything? There are only two concerns when it come to links? 1: If a request packet is sent with the URL in the header does it return 200 response code? 2: Does nGram analysis return any semantically useful terms, phrases, or language that can be understood and analyzed? If YES, then what is the concern?

Comment: @closetnoc The concern is that there are already documents and articles which describe the difference between using query strings or using nice URLs, and it means there are some differences with the way search engines behave to them.

Comment: The only difference between the two is that the opportunity for a full semantic meaning often exists within a so-called friendly URL. Why? Because it is a sentence. That is it. The whole advantage. This does not mean that any other URL cannot do the same.

Comment: @M98 have you ever found out? the web still has no answer to this simple question :(